# How can I extract the displayed text from a QTableWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, qt, corruption, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a subclass of `QTableWidget` with the following code:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(cellChanged(int, int)), this, SLOT(pushCellChange(int, int)), Qt::QueuedConnection);

...

void MyTableView::pushCellChange(int row, int column)
{
    QString text(item(row, column)->text());
    QByteArray data = text.toAscii();
    cout << data.length() << endl;
    const char* cellData = text.toAscii().constData();
    cout << "Cell ("<<row<<", "<<column<<") changed to: " << cellData << endl;
}
```

When I change the upper-right cell to anything this outputs:

```
2
Cell (0, 0) changed to: ▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌░▬∟C▌▌
```

However, while this corrupt data is spewed out on the console, the table widget itself seems to behave normally and shows the correct string. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call `toAscii()` is storing the `QString`'s data to a `QByteArray`.  In your code, you do this twice:

```
QByteArray data = text.toAscii();

const char* cellData = text.toAscii().constData();
                       _____________^ <-- temporary QByteArray
```

The `const char*` is actually pointing to the data within a temporary variable, which goes out of scope at the semicolon, at which point the pointer becomes invalid. If instead you were to make use of the local variable `data`, you'd be OK:

```
const char* cellData = data.constData();
                       ___^ <-- still-in-scope QByteArray
```

Alternatively, you can do this all in-line with the cout and the data will still be valid when it is copied to the output stream:

```
cout << "Cell ("<<row<<","<<column<<") changed to: " << text.toAscii().constData() << endl;
```

Comment: This fixes the problem; help me understand why. I thought that in C++ a variable is not destructed until it goes out of scope, and `data` does not truly go out of scope until _after_ the `cout` statement. Is the compiler actually allowed to reclaim it earlier if it isn't used?

Comment: @Calvin `data` doesn't go out of scope... but you're not taking a pointer to `data`. `const char* cellData = data.constData()` would work; instead, you were doing `text.toAscii().constData()`. See the difference?

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string cellData = text.ToStdString();
cout << "Cell ("<<row<<", "<<column<<") changed to: " << cellData << endl;
```

That should work fine.  As for why `toAscii` *doesn't* work, I have no clue.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work. I am at a complete loss as to why. Possibly it is because `text` is being destructed too early?

Comment: @Calvin Well that's interesting.  That shouldn't be an issue, although you can set a breakpoint to see if something weird does happen, and to make sure the text is valid.  Glad to see you found something that does work though!

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about the console output, you could also use qDebug() (available after `#include <QDebug>`) and pass the `QString` directly:

```
void MyTableView::pushCellChange(int row, int column)
{
    qDebug() << item(row, column)->text().length();
    qDebug() << "Cell (" << row << ", " << column << ") changed to: "
             << item(row, column)->text();
}
```

This way, you don't have to mess with data conversion …